# Media Libraries missing after upgrading Kentico 11 to 12

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

Just completed a trail run of Kentico 11 upgrade to Kentico 12, using https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/installation/upgrading-to-kentico-12

The company website is ASP.NET MVC.

The upgrade process updated Kentico CMS code and the database.

Upgrade completed without any issues.

All media libraries are gone. There are no folders in Kentico's Media Library app.

Connections strings in web.config for both Kentico CMS and MVC app are correct. Both deployed to local IIS 10.

**

> Is there any way to copy them from Kentico 11 database?

**

Any help greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

Kentico 11 database has the media libraries, but is not showing any library ***files*** in the CMS app; same thing with Kentico 12 CMS app.

The files are present in the MEDIA_FILE tables of both database. The table data matches exactly with the Kentico 12 database.

Then why are they not showing up in the CMS App of either K11 or K12??

**EDIT 2**

File system folder structure of media library under MVC site: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixc2B.jpg

Settings > System > Files > Storage screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qvos.jpg

Settings > Content > Media > Storage screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3BbS.jpg

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail to your question?  Was v11 MVC or Portal Engine?  Did you upgrade your code and database or start with a new code install of v12?

Comment: @BrendenKehren just updated

Comment: I think it might have been connected to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61035875/ysod-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-cms-dataengine-after-kentico-11-0-0-upgra

Have you redeployed both CMS and MVC apps? Also, have you cleared browser cookies and local storage before logging into upgraded admin? Have seen a couple of times that there were cookie problems.

Answer (score 1):

MVC uses web farms to sync media libraries from the CMS install to the MVC website.

1. Are your files are actually in the file system under the original location.
2. did you change the site's code name.  If you did this will cause problems with the location of the files for the media libaray as the media library uses the site's code name as a starting folder path in the file system.
3. Check the database.  Query the database tables `media_library` and 'media_files' and see if your media libraries and files are still there.  If they are, then simply find your media files and put them back in the file system in the proper location.
4. If all those are good, check the Web Farm app in Kentico and see how many web farm servers are in the table.  If you see 2, then you should be good.
5. If the web farms servers are good, check the web farm tasks in Kentico.  If there are none or some in there, great.  Query the web farm tables and look for orphaned tasks.  They will be orphaned if the server's ID is on a task but the server does not exist.  You will need to delete those orphaned tasks manually in the database as they won't show in the table anywhere.

Comment: yes i had updated the CMS node name in web farm using the `<add key="CMSWebFarmServerName" value="Kentico12CMS" />` web.config. I will revert it back. what is the purpose of `<add key="CMSApplicationName" value="kentico/Kentico_12" />`?

Comment: yes media library folders are there in the database

Comment: Both `CMS_WebFarmTask` and `CMS_WebFarmServerTask`  tables are empty. no orphaned tasks. media libraries came back in Kentico CMS after reverting the node name in server farm through web.config setting. But the files are still not showing up on MVC website.

Comment: 2 nodes in web farm and both are healthy

Comment: Media Libray folders are there in Kentico 12 just like they were in Kentico 11. But files are missing. Restarted web farm servers. What else can I try?

Comment: `Media_File` table in Kentico database has all the correct files. They're just not showing up in Kentico UI. And neither on MVC website

Comment: Do not add add the `CMSWebFarmServerName`. In settings make sure it's set to automatically add servers.  Does your site's code name match the folder name in the root of the CMS directory?

Comment: Yes Web Farm mode is already set to automatic. Upgrade did not turn it off as the documentation said. Sorry did not understand "Does your site's code name match the folder name in the root of the CMS directory?" Do you mean MVC site's name of Kentico CMS site name?

Comment: The site's code name as defined in the Sites application.  There is a display name and a code name.  The code name is used to define what the folder name is for the media library.

Comment: Kentico 11 database has the media libraries, but even that is not showing the library files in the CMS app. The files are present in the MEDIA_FILE table. The table data matches exactly with the Kentico 12 database. Then why are they not showing up in the CMS App of either K11 or K12??

Comment: So this sounds as if it's not an upgrade problem if it persisted in v11 correct?  Can you post a screenshot of your media folder structure in the file system which has the base media library folders in it?  Secondly, can you post what your settings are for media files in Settings > System > Files > Storage and also Settings > Content > Media > Storage.

Comment: Yes MVC site code name matches the media library folder name

Comment: file system folder structure of media library under MVC site: https://imgur.com/nc6ABaE

Comment: Settings > System > Files > Storage: https://imgur.com/ltjowaH

Comment: Settings > Content > Media > Storage: https://imgur.com/DZn2ows

Comment: This is an upgrade problem. The problem was not there in v11. All image files were working just before the upgrade on v11 database/CMS. It was only after the upgrade that the media files vanished from the user interface of media libraries application in v11 AND v12

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211082/discussion-between-brenden-kehren-and-joym8).